# Showing one value outside the table from joined tables in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this three tables that i joined, those tables are: attendance, employee, and division

this is my model to show the data

```
function lihatData()
{
    $this->db->select('attendance.emp_code, attendance.emp_name,division.name_division,attendance.date,attendance.time_in, attendance.time_out');    
    $this->db->from('attendance');
    $this->db->join('employee', 'employee.emp_code = attendance.emp_code');
    $this->db->join('division', 'employee.id_division = divisiob.id_division');
    $this->db->where_in('division.id_division',$this->session->userdata('id_division')
}
```

this is my view

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><center>No</center></th>
                <th><center>EMP CODE</center></th>
                <th><center>NAME</center></th>
                <th><center>DIVISION</center></th>
                <th><center>DATE</center></th>
                <th><center>TIME IN</center></th>
                <th><center>TIME OUT</center></th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
        $no = 1;
        if(is_array($data)){
        foreach($data as $row){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $no++;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->emp_code; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->emp_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->name_division; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row->date))?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->time_in; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->time_out; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } }?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is what i got from my code:
[image: this is the result]

So what i need to change the results into something like this:

```
                 Division : Redaksi (based on user's division)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|    emp code   |    name   |   date   |   time in   |   time out  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

UPDATE: I already managed to group the division into a table, and here's the result:

[image: table after grouped]

As you can see, its already show datas of user's division. but i need to remove the division table, and change it into some kind of table's name or put the division's name at the top of the table based on user's name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible solution would be to extract data from your first `array` Item, something like the following should work

```
<?php
if (is_array($data) && count($data) > 0)
{
?>
<h1><?=$data[0]->nama_division; ?></h1>
<?php
}
?>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
 <thead>
 <tr>
    <th><center>No</center></th>
    <th><center>EMP CODE</center></th>
    <th><center>NAME</center></th>
    <th><center>DATE</center></th>
    <th><center>TIME IN</center></th>
    <th><center>TIME OUT</center></th>

 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php 
 $no = 1;
 if(is_array($data))
 {
    foreach($data as $row){
 ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no++;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->emp_code; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->emp_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row->date))?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->time_in; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->time_out; ?></td>
     </tr>
<?php 
    } 
 }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey @sintakonte , at first it didn't work because of the `<h1><?=$data[0]['name_division']; ?></h1>` but then i edited it to `<h1>Divisi: <?php echo $data[0]->nama_division; ?></h1>` and it worked! Thank you so much sir! :D

Answer (score 0):

function lihatData()
{

```
$this->db->from('attendance');
$this->db->join('employee', 'employee.emp_code = attendance.emp_code');
$this->db->join('division', 'employee.id_division = divisiob.id_division');
$this->db->where_in('division.id_division',$division);
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

}

try this

Comment: im sorry but i was questioning on how can i show a  division outside the table based on user's division. currently i have no problems with the inner join, just wondering on how can i get the division name outside the table

Answer (score 0):

The key is how to group result by division. I think you can sort the result array by division, or group it as follow:

```
$sortedResult = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $sortedResult[$row->name_division] = $row;
}

//Render
<?php foreach ($sortedResult as $devision => $data) { ?>
<div><?php echo $devision; ?></div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><center>No</center></th>
            <th><center>EMP CODE</center></th>
            <th><center>NAME</center></th>
            <th><center>DATE</center></th>
            <th><center>TIME IN</center></th>
            <th><center>TIME OUT</center></th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $no = 1;
    foreach($data as $row){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no++;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->emp_code; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->emp_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row->date))?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->time_in; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->time_out; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php }?>

    </tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i tried your answer by putting the $sorted result and it doesn't work.. Actually i already managed to group it by the divsion, by using where_in through my model and it worked, it shows the whole data for user's division. but my problem now is i need to show the data without the division row, which means i have to put the division's name either outside the table as a label or on the top of the table as a part of the table head, but i don't know how to call the division's :(